# render HTML elements in reverse order

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation that's supposed to imitate the look of classical notebook with bookmarks. The problem is that HTML renders it in a way the last element (bookmark) renders on top of the second-to-last and so on so it looks unnatural. Any way around this (except asigning each bookmark its z-index)? Thank you

```
<div class="nav_button">Wall</div>
<div class="nav_button">Guidelines</div>
<div class="nav_button">Ref</div>
```

http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/2121/notebookbookmarks.jpg (Undesired effect)

Comment: What's wrong with using z-index? It's designed for that.

Comment: Well, if you had just few bookmarks, then ok. But if there are many, dynamically created bookmarks, it gets pretty messy.

Comment: Post the code you use to generate them

Comment: @David nothing a little variable couldn't manage for you while generating them =P

Comment: @AllisonC I do not as of yet, just researching possibilities and best ways around it. And yes, I could get the bookmarks out of database, count them, assign each of them z-index based on that and so on. But I am afraid sometime in the future I am just gonna get lost in all the z-indexing everywhere. Who knows what else I am going to be using z-indexing for, next time.

Comment: Then I suppose you can do it by using a different background for the first div, where the ones below have the top part cut out (so it doesn't overlap) and the one on top has it displayed.

Comment: I'll just go with the z-indexing. Probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far no other way then to use the good ol' z-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Or use an image like this one and position it at the bottom of the element:

http://i.minus.com/ibivyqVAVLqnQt.jpg

then use an alternative image for first & last child.